Difference between water soluble and hydrolysed
What is the basic difference between a substance being water soluble and a substance being hydrolyzed.
Carbohydrates sugars are water soluble but monosaccharides cannot be hydrolyze. What does it mean?

Hydrolyzed means that the compound decomposed in an reversible or irreversible (in a literal sense) in the presence of water.
The term solubility does not indicate decomposition. For example, table sugar readily dissolves in water, it is a disaccharide (sucrose). If you evaporate water you will recover all of it. However, it we hydrolyze this sugar in an aqueous acid solution, say by boiling it with aqueous HCl, we cannot recover the original sugar if we evaporate water and acid solution. It would have broken down into simpler units, glucose and fructose.
Monosaccharides like glucose cannot be hydrolyzed means that if you try to break them down in water into a simpler sugar unit, this will not happen.
Hydrolysis does not require that the substrate be water soluble completely.
Transition metals salts can also hydrolyze in water.

“Hydrolysis” means to break a bond as a substance reacts with water. Typically, the bond is a single bond, and the molecule is broken into two fragments.
If a substance is water soluble, it can form an aqueous solution. If it is ionic, the ions will separate. If it is molecular, the intermolecular interactions between molecules will break and be replaced by intermolecular interactions with water. Those water molecules are called a sphere of hydration.
Hydrolysis usually occurs in aqueous solution, so typically molecules undergoing hydrolysis are water-soluble. However, there are counter examples, such as the hydrolysis of oils into glycerol and fatty acids. In this case, the reaction happens at the interface of the aqueous and the non-aqueous phase.
